# Would there be 6p½ -> π* backbonding in oganesson tetracyanide?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, relativistic

It is known that oganesson, although a group 18 element, is more likely to behave like a group (1)4 element; i.e. with 4 valence electrons outside a flerovium core. This contributes to the fact that the 7s and 6p½ orbitals are likely "inert pairs" and should not affect the geometry of oganesson tetrafluoride, which is thus predicted to be tetrahedral. Logically, the same would hold for oganesson tetracyanide.

However, it is well-known that "inert pairs" can sometimes engage in (generalised) backbonding; the 3 iron lone pairs in the ferrocyanide molecules are "inert pairs" (in the sense that they do not affect the complex's geometry) but nevertheless still are formally valence electrons and are shared, in a Lewis base-acid sense, to the cyanide π* orbitals.

Even though oganesson is not a transition metal, the situation in oganesson tetracyanide is similar to that of the ferrocyanide anion in the sense that,

1. the 2 oganesson lone pairs, namely the 7s and 6p½ electrons, are "inert pairs" in the sense that they do not affect the geometry of oganesson tetracyanide and
2. they are formally "valence electrons".

It is known that the 7s orbital is likely highly non-accessible for bonding from moscovium onwards; that would leave only the 6p½ orbital in oganesson potentially available for generalised backbonding(the 7s orbital has the wrong symmetry anyway), via donation into the cyanide π* orbitals, in oganesson tetracyanide.

My question now follows- do theoretical calculations on oganesson, and/or its tetrafluoride, support what I have written here?

Comment: Oganesson only known isotope has a half-life of $0.89$ millisecond. It will never find the time to be included in a compound or an ion. So, up to now, its chemistry is non-existant. As a consequence, does it make sense to discuss about the theoretical properties of an unknown cyanide, which would last less than a millisecond, if it could ever be synthesized ?

Comment: That's why I wrote every sentence in my post with a doubt and put the "theoretical" part in my final question.

Comment: "It is known that oganesson, although a group 18 element, is more likely to behave like a group (1)4 element". Wow, we've learned a lot! 

Comment: Discussing about the chemical properties of Oganession is like talking about the angels sex, or about the inhabitants of extragalactic planets. Why ?

Comment: Then why would there exist legitimate pieces of research on oganesson in the literature?